# react-hook-form not working with Astro and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, astrojs

I'm using Astro with React, and using Shadcn-ui for some components.

I used the Form Component and copied the code provided by shadcn to use on my own site, but it seems that react-hook-form doesn't provide several methods such as `Controllerprops`, even though they show up in the IDE.

The exact error I get is:

> The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-hook-form.js?v=b115cd0f' does not provide an export named 'ControllerProps'

```react
import {
    Button,
    Input,
    Textarea,
    Form,
    FormLabel,
    FormControl,
    FormItem,
    FormMessage,
    FormField
} from '@/components/ui';
import React from 'react';
import * as z from 'zod';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const requiredError = {
    required_error: 'Dies ist ein Pflichtfeld'
};

const formSchema = z.object({
    email: z.string(requiredError).email({ message: 'Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Email an' }),
    name: z.string(requiredError),
    subject: z.string(requiredError),
    message: z.string(requiredError)
});

type Email = z.infer<typeof formSchema>;

export default function ContactForm() {
    const form = useForm<Email>({
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
        defaultValues: {
            name: '', email: '', subject: '', message: ''
        }
    });

    function onSubmit(values: Email) {
        console.log(values);
    }


    return (
        <Form {...form}>
            <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className='space-y-5'>
                {Object.keys(form.getValues()).map(name => (
                    <FormField
                        control={form.control}
                        name={name}
                        key={name}
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormItem>
                                <FormLabel className='capitalize'>{name}</FormLabel>
                                <FormControl>
                                    {name == 'message' ?
                                        <Textarea rows={5} {...field} /> :
                                        <Input {...field} />
                                    }
                                </FormControl>
                                <FormMessage />
                            </FormItem>
                        )}
                    />
                ))}

                <Button type='submit'>Senden</Button>
            </form>
        </Form>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue, and solved it as follows:

shadcn gives you the actual components.

If you notice, the only place you're using RHF's controller, is in FormField's control, via form.control:

```
<FormField
                        control={form.control}
                        name={name}
                        key={name}
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormItem>
                                <FormLabel className='capitalize'>{name}</FormLabel>
                                <FormControl>
                                    {name == 'message' ?
                                        <Textarea rows={5} {...field} /> :
                                        <Input {...field} />
                                    }
                                </FormControl>
                                <FormMessage />
                            </FormItem>
```

If you follow FormField, you will get to the form.tsx file that shadcn injected into your project.

There, you should see red: typescript telling you **ControllerProps, FieldPath, FieldValues** must be imported as types.

So, change the default import to this:

```
import {
  Controller,
  FormProvider,
  useFormContext,
} from "react-hook-form"

import type { ControllerProps, FieldPath, FieldValues } from "react-hook-form"
```

...which means you just have to separate ControllerProps, FieldPath, FieldValues into their own type import.

Now try again, it should be working.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried it and it works. Just want to clarify that you add the `import type` shadcn generated component in `ui/form.tsx`, not in your own react component that use `form` component.